# How to click on the Hcaptcha using puppeteer-extra

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, puppeteer, captcha, hcaptcha

I'm using puppeteer-extra and trying to click on recaptcha and I can't find a solution for two days in google
I tried more than one way and it didn't work
I want it to click on the checkbox automatically using puppeteer

**My problem is not in solving the captcha, my problem is in clicking on its checkbox**

[image: I'm trying to click the checkbox button but I can't]

```html
This is iframe Selector :
#app-mount > div.app-1q1i1E > div > div > div > section > div > div.flexCenter-3_1bcw.flex-1O1GKY.justifyCenter-3D2jYp.alignCenter-1dQNNs > div > iframe
This is iframe :
<iframe src="https://newassets.hcaptcha.com/captcha/v1/f9bf301/static/hcaptcha-checkbox.html#id=29x2xvbwuudm&amp;host=discord.com&amp;sentry=true&amp;reportapi=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.hcaptcha.com&amp;recaptchacompat=true&amp;custom=false&amp;hl=en&amp;tplinks=on&amp;sitekey=f5561ba9-8f1e-40ca-9b5b-a0b3f719ef34&amp;theme=dark" title="widget containing checkbox for hCaptcha security challenge" tabindex="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" data-hcaptcha-widget-id="29x2xvbwuudm" data-hcaptcha-response="" style="width: 303px; height: 78px; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
--------
This is checkbox :
<div id="checkbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-checked="false" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" aria-live="assertive" aria-labelledby="a11y-label" style="position: absolute; width: 28px; height: 28px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); border-radius: 4px; background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250); top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
```

```
await page.waitForFunction(`#app-mount > div.app-1q1i1E > div > div > div > section > div > 
div.flexCenter-3_1bcw.flex-1O1GKY.justifyCenter-3D2jYp.alignCenter-1dQNNs > div > iframe`)

await page.click(`#checkbox`),
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-hcaptcha

Answer (score 1):

Your selector seems to be wrong.
When hcaptcha launches, it generates random class names (hashes), so you can't try on your machine, get the class name, and put it in production, because every execution is a different class name.